# How to start creating HTML5 video gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I'm trying to learn how to make a video gallery with html5. I'm looking for tutorials and information to this but I only find information to make video galleries based on videos that are on youtube or vimeo or gender sites. But what I wanted is to create a video gallery with videos that I have stored on my computer disk. Does anyone know how can I do this? What is the js plugin or something that i can use to learn how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure but these might help you;
*http://easyhtml5video.com/*

*http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/adding-video-to-your-website-using-the-new-html5-video-tag*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

It works just fine with videos stored localy: http://html5box.com/html5gallery/